# Cannot got JMagick working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jmagick

I have strange problem with JMagick library. I use Debian, so I have installed libjmagick6-java and libjmagick6-jni, and here are steps I have done:

- I have copied `jmagick-6.6.9.jar` from `/usr/share/java/` to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/`.
- I have set `/usr/lib/jni` (where is `libJMagick.so`) as native library location in:

  - JRE System library (in eclipse)
  - jmagick-6.6.9.jar (in eclipse)

Also I have tested JMagick in simple Java project and there it works, but in the second project which is web application running in Tomcat 6, it just doesn't work..

Here is my code which **WORKS** - so jmagick must be installed right:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        MagickImage image = null;
        ImageInfo imageInfo = null;

        try {
            imageInfo = new ImageInfo("/home/firzen/IMG_0120.JPG");
            image = new MagickImage(imageInfo);
            System.out.println(image.getDimension().width);
        } catch (MagickException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
        }
        image.destroyImages();
    }
}
```

And here is the code in webapp which is **NOT WORKING**:

```
public void init() {        
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    cacheHandlers = (Map<String, CacheContext>) sc.getAttribute("handlers");
    Boolean applicationReady = (Boolean) sc.getAttribute("ready");
    isReady = cacheHandlers != null && Boolean.TRUE.equals(applicationReady);

    System.out.println("zde");
    MagickImage image = null;
    ImageInfo imageInfo = null;

    try {
        imageInfo = new ImageInfo("/home/firzen/IMG_0120.JPG");
        image = new MagickImage(imageInfo);
        System.out.println(image.getDimension().width);
    } catch (MagickException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
    }
    image.destroyImages();
}
```

Finally here is the exception thrown by mentioned code:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at magick.Magick.<clinit>(Magick.java:18)
    at cz.bach.mrimage.MrImageSrv.init(MrImageSrv.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please tell me some ideas how to solve this problem.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem by checking the real java.library.path with:

```
System.out.println("java.library.path is: " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

This gave me this mess:

```
java.library.path is: /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server:/opt/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386:/opt/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
```

At the end you can see /usr/lib, so I have created link to libJMagick.so in /usr/lib by:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libJMagick.so /usr/lib/libJMagick.so
```

Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Good plan, didn't work. I've done it on 5 previous installations and it would randomly stop detecting the native library at times. `libJMagick.so` is absolutely in the `java.library.path` and so are it's dependencies, yet I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when it tries to load the class.